# Few errormessager in one raiserrror

Tags: t-sql, raiserror

I have following problem, I need to display few error messages from my if statements. If, for example, 2 of 3 conditions are met I need to raisevent display 2 messages.

```
IF @var1 > 1
BEGIN 
    SET @err = 'ASD'
END

IF @var1 <4
BEGIN 
    SET @err = 'ZXC'
END

IF @var = 3
BEGIN
   SET @err = 'QWE'
END
```

For `@var1 = 2`

I need to display 2 errormessages in one raiserror. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to raise 2 separate events ? or one event with the error messages combined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code inside BEGIN CACTH block? 
How about raising error like this with severity less than 11 that:

```
IF @var1 > 1
BEGIN 
    SET @err = 'ASD';
    RAISEERROR(@err, <your_severity>, <state>)
END

IF @var1 <4
BEGIN 
    SET @err = 'ZXC'
    RAISEERROR(@err, <your_severity>, <state>)
END

IF @var = 3
BEGIN
   SET @err = 'QWE'
   RAISEERROR(@err, <your_severity>, <state>)
END
```

Or combining message_erorr:

```
IF @var1 > 1
BEGIN 
    SET @err += ' ASD'; 
END

IF @var1 <4
BEGIN 
    SET @err += ' ZXC'
END

IF @var = 3
BEGIN
   SET @err += ' QWE'
END

RAISEERROR(@err, <your_severity>, <state>)
```